# Jquery Ajax Post failed after Serialize [jquery / javascript]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have search other post but no answer works for me. I have Cross-Domain issue fixed so cross-domain issue is not the problem here.

**My javascript/jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("http://mydomain.com/api/user/register",

//    {
//      email:"donald@duck.com",
//      name:"Duckburg"
//    }

    $("loginForm").serialize(),
    function(data,status){
      $("#loginresult").text("Data: " + data + " /nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
});
```

**My HTML code:**

```
<!--    page 3 [userLogin] -->
<div data-role="page" id="userlogin">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div>
            <form  action="/" id="loginForm">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
            <button id="loginButton"/>Submit</button>
            </form>
            <a href="#welcome" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-back-black" data-transition="flow" data-direction="reverse">Back to Main Screen</a>
        </div>
        <div id="loginresult"></div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- page 3 end -->
```

**My PHP code:**

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$file = fopen("capture.txt","w");
fwrite($file,$email . "\n");
fclose($file);
echo $email;
```

The above Ajax call will success if I use the commented {object} as data input upon Post.

But if I use serialize() as data input, the Ajax call will fail. Server side doesn't not receive the value as well because it doesn't write to the text file.

I have read the documentation many times over and over again as well as other tutorials I can get via google. But it's just don't work.

Comment: `$("loginForm")` you mean `$("#loginForm")`

Comment: what did you mean by "you have x-domain fixed"? you could never HTTP POST to a different domain without using HTML5 messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit data part as:

```
$("#loginForm").serialize(),
```